Character of a kac-moody module as the sum of characters of Verma modules
I'm trying to prove the next result from Kac's book, Infinite dimensional Lie algebras.

Let $V$ be a $\mathfrak{g}(A)$-module with highest weight $\Lambda$. Then
$$
\text{ch}(V)=\sum_{\lambda\in B(\Lambda)}c_{\lambda}\text{ch}(M(\lambda)),
$$
where $c_{\lambda}\in \mathbb{Z}$, $c_{\Lambda}=1$ and $B(V)=\{\lambda\leq\Lambda | |\lambda+\rho|^{2}=|\Lambda+\rho|^{2}\}$

So far, I have the next system of equations
$$
\text{ch}(M(\lambda_{i}))=\sum_{\lambda_{j}\in B(\Lambda)}[M(\lambda_{i}):L(\lambda_{j})]\text{ch}(L(\lambda_{j}))
$$
and I can write $[M(\lambda_{i}):L(\lambda_{j})]$ as $c_{ij}$ such that it equals $0$ when $i>j$ but I'm not sure what happens when $i=j$
In order to prove that $c_{\Lambda}=1$ my intuition tells that $c_{ii}$ must be equals to $1$ but I'm having problems understandin this part. I know that for a given $\lambda_{j}$ there exist a filtration such that $0=V_{0}\subseteq V_{1}\subseteq\dots\subseteq V_{t}=M(\lambda_{i})$ and $L(\lambda_{i})\cong V_{j}/V_{j-1}$ for some j. I know that the Verma module $M(\lambda_{i})$ is not necessarily irreducible so it doesn't have to be equal to $L(\lambda_{i})$.
In order to this to be true, I should prove first that said $V_{j-1}={0}$ and I really don't know if that's even possible.
Can you guys give a hint o tell me what should I do in order to prove this?
